# Use share element transition and slide at the same time when starting an activity

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I want to launch a new activity with shared element transition on a particular view, and at the same time let other views slide in from the bottom.

Currently I can only implement the shared element transition part, and the other views just stay stationary. How do I add the slide transition at the same time?

```
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat
        .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                WeekScheduleActivity.this,
                v,
                "trans_card"
        ).toBundle();
Intent intent = new Intent(WeekScheduleActivity.this, CourseDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("course_object",course);

startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make changes in second activity for that. Write this in your onCreate of 2nd activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        slide.addTarget(R.id.description);
        slide.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.interpolator
                .linear_out_slow_in));
        slide.setDuration(slideDuration);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
    }
```

You can find a working example of the the effect you want to achieve here:
https://github.com/anshchauhan/SharedElementTransition